# How to make underLeft view scrollable on ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using ECSlidingViewController in my Application.

My main menu viewController is underLeft on ECSlidingViewController, which is UItableView with UINavationController, is it possible make it scrollable?

Thanks,

Comment: It should be scrollable already. There must be something else going on.